# Why do we use the moments of the stock returns?

Tags: inference, finance, moments

Why do we use the moments of the stock returns instead of calculating directly the stock's moments? For example why do we use the standard deviation of the returns to measure the standard deviation  of the stock?
Sorry if this question is very simple but I still keep trying to find the answer.

Comment: " the stock returns instead of calculating directly the stock's moments" - what does this mean? What is "stock's moments"? there's no such a thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not so sure the question does not belong here. It does have a financial aspect to it, but the essence of the answer is purely statistical. Once we go from prices and returns to random walks and their increments, there is no finance to speak of, only statistics.

Comment: @F.G could you clarify whether by "the stock's moments" you mean the moments of the price of the stock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If stock prices can be approximately considered to be random walks, they are nonstationary and so their moments do not exist (e.g. the second moment and also variance are infinite). You can always calculate the sample moments but they will not be meaningful estimates of the population moments since the latter do not exist. Hence, using the sample moments for inference about population or for forecasting would be misleading and probably dangerous.

Meanwhile, stock returns could be considered stationary and so have some lower-order moments (e.g. the second moment and variance are probably finite). Therefore, you can use the calculated sample moments to get insight into the population moments, which is useful for inference and forecasting.

Comment: I think OP is asking about returns vs. prices. I can guess by the phrasing

Comment: @Aksakal, indeed, that is how I understood it, too, as you can see from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize to all members if my question was not very clear or posted in the wrong forum, my mistake.

Comment: @F.G, you are welcome. As you can see by calculating the close votes vs. the votes on the comment suggesting the question should not be closed, it was 4+1 (the comment author cannot vote) against 5, so it is indeed far from a consensus that your question did not belong here. I am glad you found the answer helpful.